# Why do we have that for example $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5, \sqrt{11}) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt5)(\sqrt{11})$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

> Why do we have that for example $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5, \sqrt{11}) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt5)(\sqrt{11})$?

I'm trying to understand what this means. The lhs of the equality is supposed to be the smallest field containing $\Bbb Q$ and $\sqrt5$ as well as $\sqrt{11}$.

The rhs is from what I can understand the smallest field containing $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ and $\sqrt{11}$?

Is there some simple way to see why this equality holds? And is it true for every $a,b \in \Bbb R$ that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt a, \sqrt{b}) = \Bbb Q(\sqrt a)(\sqrt{b})$?

Comment: The left hand side says that we extend the rationals to include both radicals; the right hand side says we extend the rationals with $\sqrt{5}$ and further extend that field with $\sqrt{11}$.

Comment: Show that each is a subset of the other?  And yes, as long as you fix a field extension $K \subset L$ where $\alpha, \beta \in L$, then $K(\alpha, \beta) = K(\alpha)(\beta)$ always, and the proof of this general fact is no more difficult than your instance of it.

Comment: If that is how they defined them for you, then you could verify that they contain the same elements of $\mathbb{C}$ or whichever larger field they are taking as universe to consider the minima. You can verify that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{11})$ consists of all $a+b\sqrt{5}+c\sqrt{11}+d\sqrt{55}$, with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$. In the case of $K(\sqrt{11})$ that they are $a+b\sqrt{11}$ with $a,b\in K$. To verify that these sets of elements form fields, the only tricky step is division, but you can multiply and divide by all conjugates of the denominator.

Comment: In your case $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, which consists of $x+y\sqrt{5}$, with $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$. So, $a,b$ in $a+b\sqrt{11}$ in this form gives $(x_1+y_1\sqrt{5})+(x_2+y_2\sqrt{5})\sqrt{11}$ and expanding gives an expression of the form $A+B\sqrt{5}+C\sqrt{11}+D\sqrt{55}$, with $A,B,C,D\in\mathbb{Q}$. Similarly, an $a+b\sqrt{5}+c\sqrt{11}+d\sqrt{55}$ can be written as $(a+b\sqrt{5})+(c+d\sqrt{5})\sqrt{11}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed true much more generally. But let's first get a handle on what these things mean.

Like you said, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is the "smallest field" containing $\mathbb{Q}$ as well as $\sqrt{5}$. To be more precise, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is the smallest *subfield of $\mathbb{R}$* which contains both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{5}$.

More generally, when you have a subfield $F$ of a field $K$, and elements $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in K$, then $F(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$ denotes the smallest subfield of $K$ which contains both $F$ and the elements $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$. It's important to keep in mind what this larger field $K$ is, even though it is usually only implicitly specified through context!

So, in your case:

- $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{5}$.
- $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{11})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains both $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\sqrt{11}$. Combining this with the previous step, this means that is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains $\mathbb{Q}$, $\sqrt{5}$, and $\sqrt{11}$.
- $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{11})$ is, by definition, the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains $\mathbb{Q}$, $\sqrt{5}$, and $\sqrt{11}$.
- Thus, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{11}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{11})$.

---

This argument is perhaps a bit lacking in rigor, and if you'd like you remedy that, you should start by writing down what exactly it means that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is "the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{5}$". Let me know if you try this and get stuck!

---

Challenge yourself: can you see why more generally we have

$F(\alpha_1)(\alpha_2)\dots(\alpha_n) = F(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$

for any field $F$ and any elements $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ in a superfield $K$ of $F$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the intuition about $\mathbb Q({\root 3 \of 2})$ being "the smallest field extension of $\mathbb Q$ containing ${\root 3 \of 2}$ is definitely correct. But there turn out to be glitches in this, so some refinement is needed.

At least eventually, you'll not want to think of field extensions of $\mathbb Q$ as being subfields of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, because fields like $\mathbb Q({\root 3 \of 2})$ have three different imbeddings into $\mathbb C$, exactly one of which has image inside $\mathbb R$, with the image of ${\root 3 \of 2}$ being the real cube root.

It turns out to be better, again, at least eventually, to follow Kronecker, and say that $\mathbb Q({\root 3 \of 2})=\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle$, somewhat abstractly. And, yes, this "abstract" field has 3 different imbeddings to $\mathbb C$, etc.